# Аналог Intelliji IDEA помогите

Tags: intellij-idea, eclipse, ide

Intelliji IDEA тормозит на ноуте, не справляется он - решил гуглить тип аналоги, а именно из чего состоит IDE любое: компилятор ,отладчик ,редактор, транслятор, система авт. сборки. **А что в IDE подчеркивает ошибки в коде и помогает с вариантами продолжения слов, классов, методов, ключевых слов и т.п.**;т.е. я хочу в Notepad++ писать код, через cmd и Java компилить .Eclipse тоже тормозит :)

Ноутбук:https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeYky.jpg

Comment: а конфиг компа можете в вопрос добавить?

Comment: добавлю.А что должно быть супер-друпер-пупер в ноуте чтоб не было с этим проблем?

Comment: что-то одно определенное выделить сложно, так как оно идет в комплексе

Comment: Может Sublime text подойдет для твоих нужд?)

Comment: Для продуктов Jet Brains желательно оперативной памяти 8 Гб как минимум. Ну и процессор не совсем уж слабый. В целом нужен редактор кода (не очень важно какой - хоть Vscode, хоть Sublime Text) + JDK + желательно система сборки (например, maven или gradle).

Comment: Можете попробовать netbeans. Но сомневаюсь, что нотебуку будет проще. Все эти IDE для java требуют от системы приметно того же. Ну а если через командную строку компилить, то полезно знать какие системы сборки есть для java. Maven пожалуй самая популярная. Так подавляющее большинство библиотек для java распространяются через maven. Есть ещё ant, gradle.